# What are untracked files in a Git repository?

Tags: git, github, repository

What exactly are untracked files in a repository?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files in a repo folder that have not been added to the index.

So for instance, if I do:

git diff HEAD^ > some-new-file.diff

Then `some-new-file.diff` is probably untracked, since I've never done a `git add` on it before.

Answer (score 1):

Untracked files are new files which have never been staged(added using `git add`).

> - let's say you had some files you have been working with before now (which you have previously staged using `git add`). when you make a change in them. Git refers to them as `Modified files`
> - on the other hand, when you add a new file to the project directory i.e you freshly added a `Readme.md` file and added some content. Git refers to such a file as an untracked file because it has no stagging/commit history

Answer (score 0):

Untracked files are those files which git is unaware about. Say you create a new file in your project. Git will consider that file as untracked(or unaware in more simple terms). Now we need to tell Git that this file also exist(also called as staging the file) which we can do by `git commit` or `git push` commands